# Open submenu on mouse hover

Tags: html, css

I have a menu in side bar, and when user keep mouse on that menu, it should open sub menu if it has.How can I write css for that menu.
//This is the css for my side bar

```
sidebar
{
background-color: #cdf;
width:24.5%;
/*width:25%;*/
float:left;
clear:both;
display:inline;
position:relative;

}
#sidebar a
{
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: medium;
display:block;
padding:5px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#sidebar a:hover
{
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:underline;
background-color:White;
}
#sidebar ul
{
list-style-type:none;
display:block;
margin:0px;
width:100%;
padding:0;
}

#sidebar li
{
display:block;
border:1px solid white;
}
```

This is my side bar in .aspx page

```
<div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="CompanyList.aspx">Company</a></li>
                <li><a href="DepartmentList.aspx">Department</a></li>
                <li><a href="UserList.aspx">Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="UserTypeListFrm.aspx">User Type</a></li>
                <li><a href="QualificationList.aspx">Qualifications</a></li>
                <li><a href="../logOutfrm.aspx">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=css%20submenu) is [full](http://www.google.com/search?q=css%20multiple%20dropdowns) of [examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=suckerfish) of [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=css%20submenu%20list).

Comment: @dtbarne..I searched so many articles but didnt find any script, it only provide menu paid builders

Answer (score 0):

**dtbarne** was right. Google is full of examples, and they are free. you can even use an [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) to create this kind of menu.